# Did Goku use the Kaio-ken to stop Gohan in a what if scenario?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

I don't know which video game depicted this but I think it's the one where Janemba possessed Super Saiyan 2 Teen Gohan. I don't know if this is true, but to subdue or possibly knock out Gohan, Goku used the Kaio-Ken to attack. I checked the Dragonball wiki but I think it was edited out by someone